# Can't see the Armature in Object Mode and in Weight Painting Mode in blender 2.8

Tags: armature, weight-painting

For whatever reason, If I'm seeing the model in Object Mode the Armature hides, same in Weight Painting Mode, I can select it but the Armature doesn't show, the only thing that shows representing the Armature is a orange dot placed where the Root is. Alt+H doesn't show it.

Comment: Are you sure that the In Front option is enabled in the Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display?

Comment: Yes, "In Front" is checked.

Comment: could you please share your file (at least a part that we can test): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6565/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug or a bad design, maybe someone will tell, anyway, to fix it:

- In the *Outliner*, click on and unfold *Pose*, unhide all the bones.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to come back to *Edit* mode.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to come back to *Pose* mode. Your bones are now visible, both in *Pose* and *Object* mode.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you disabled *Bones* in the *Viewport Overlay* options?
The options are at the two intersecting circles on the top right.

Comment: No, Bones option is checked.

Comment: This was my issue thanks

Answer (score 4):

**if it is a glitch**, the 100% working solution is to make a new project and copy-paste all objects from your project containing the glitch into your new one, and replace your glitch project with the new one. I know this can get annoying if you have to do it often but that wont likely happen and it is my only solution either way. Hope this helps but if it doesnt then this is technically supposed to happen and you must have accedentally changed a setting or something, not a glitch.

Answer (score 4):

Unhide All and recursively unhiding didn't work, scale was correct and position was 0,0,0. Select all and numpad . wasn't zooming anywhere. I was in object mode with solid shading and viewport display was octahedral for all bones. Wireframe mode did nothing, the bones simply weren't there whatsoever. Reloading the project didn't fix it.

Switching to the Compositing workflow at top (or probably any workflow) miraculously fixed it. So I'd say my experience was a bad bug. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks this helped me as well in Blender 2.83.0

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the bones *were* actually showing up -- they were just so tiny that I couldn't see them (it was just a small yellow dot on top of the origin icon).

Selecting the armature and scaling it up by about 100 made the bones 'visible' again.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Object Data Properties* and mark *In Front*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You maybe just changed position layer to one without bones.

Click your armature then *Object Data Properties > Layers*, choose the one with dot.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to unhide the armature in pose mode. Then it was visible in all other modes again. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're suppose to turn the visibility of it on. Look to the top right where the blue highlighted circles are. Click the down arrow next to the picture that shows the drawn in circle next to the transparent one. Then check mark the "bones" option thats below "objects".

Answer (score 0):

check the bones tick box in overlays dropdown in upper right corner of viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Change the workspace, at the top, works for me. After that, delete the bug workspace and add it as a new again.

[image: I delete the 2D animation Workspace and create a new one]